# Unexpected newlines in json output in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, json, export

I'm squashing a datastructure to JSON objects using the PostgreSQL Json functions, however, there are unexpected newlines in the output.

Basically, it creates JSON objects and put them in a list.

This is the SQL:

```
copy (
   select json_agg(Y.*) from (
    select
        table_logical_id as "logicalId",
        max(table_actual_name)  as "tableName",
        max(table_display_name) as "displayName",
        max(table_restriction_expression) as "restrictionExpression",
        json_strip_nulls(json_agg(
                json_build_object('field'            , column_actual_name,
                                  'type'             , case column_type when 'DATE_TIME' then 'DATE' else column_type end,
                                  'displayName'      , column_display_name,
                                  'displayLocation'  , column_display_location,
                                 )  ORDER BY column_order ASC
       )) as "columns",
    coalesce(
        json_agg(
                json_build_object(
                        'field'                 , column_actual_name,
                        'direction'             , case column_is_asc_sort when true then 'ASC' else 'DESC' end
                ) order by column_sort_order desc
        ) filter (where column_sort_order is not null)
    , '[]') as "defaultSort"

  from my_table_config
group by table_logical_id
) Y

)
TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT TEXT, ENCODING 'UTF8');
```

The output contains a literal `\n` (so 2 characters, not the line feed control character) between each json record, like this:

```
   ..."direction" : "ASC"}]}, \n {"logicalId ...
```

Is this a bug in PostgreSQL? Or, how can I prevent this?

UPDATE:
Exporting a BINARY as suggested in the answer does not work, as that returns something that starts with:

```
00000000: 5047 434f 5059 0aff 0d0a 0000 0000 0000  PGCOPY..........
00000010: 0000 0000 0100 7480 cc5b 7b22 6c6f 6769  ......t..[{"logi
00000020: 6361 6c49 6422 3a22 4155 4449 545f 3230  calId":"AUDIT_20
```

Comment: Why use `COPY (select ...)` when you don't need or want the COPY format? Why not do the SELECT query directly without any unescaping of the results?

Comment: @DanielVérité  want the text format, not the psql output with the ascii markup etc. This is standard method to get the 'clean' output.

Comment: The psql decoration is turned off with `psql -A -t` which are shortcuts to set the unaligned format (no ascii markers and padding around fields) and the "tuples_only" mode (no header/footer)

Comment: @DanielVérité thanks! That seemed to do the trick :) Can I assume it uses the default platform encoding for the output?

Comment: Yes, it's the `client_encoding` setting. It's determined from the client-side `LC_CTYPE` or can be set explicitly at connection time or later with `SET client_encoding=...`.

Answer (score 0):

The `TEXT` format is specified [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.9.2) to have each row on a new line. If there are embedded newline characters in the value then these will be encoded with `\n`.

> **Text Format**
>
> When the `text` format is used, the data read or written is a text file with one line per table row. Columns in a row are separated by the delimiter character. The column values themselves are strings generated by the output function, or acceptable to the input function, of each attribute's data type.
> *..snip..*
> The following special backslash sequences are recognized
>
> | Sequence | Represents |
> | --- | --- |
> | \n | Newline (ASCII 10) |
>
> *..snip..*
> Presently, `COPY TO` will never emit an octal or hex-digits backslash sequence, but it does use the other sequences listed above for those control characters.

Instead you probably want the `BINARY` format option.

Comment: Ah. I expected there would be only 1 (giant) row, actually.

Comment: Also  BINARY generates a custom binary format, not usable JSON

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a workaround, found here:

https://alphahydrae.com/2021/02/how-to-export-postgresql-data-to-a-json-file/

> Note that you can convert multiple rows into a JSON array with just
> json_agg, without using row_to_json, but for some reason converting
> that array to text will introduce line breaks into the resulting text,
> and the COPY command will serialize those line breaks into literal \n
> characters instead of actual line breaks.

Changing `select json_agg(Y.*)` to  `select json_agg(row_to_json(Y.*))` seems to do the trick.

Now only the output is double escaped, so I need a `sed 's/\\\\/\\/g'` before it is accepted in `jq`